# Formatting a text box

Tags: ms-access

I have a table which tracks records of employees of which within it there is a field 'Team' referencing another table where all the teams of the company are listed. Upon creating this field and given that it references another table, MS Access automatically formats this field to a numerical value.  I would like to include this field on a form in the form of a text box. Upon doing so however the form returns only the unique numerical value of the team name and not the text value.  I have tried to reformat the text box as below but the box returns an error message:

```
=[Team].[text]
```

Answer (score 0):

You shoud try this :

> [Team].Column(1)

assuming that we make this field a combo box (instead of a text field) with the Row Source of the ComboBox being equal to the SQL statement:

> "SELECT Team, Team_Name from "Teams_of_the_company";

"`Teams_of_the_company`" is referencing the table where all the teams of the company are listed